# Raspbian gMail Recurring Authentication Issue

Tags: linux, email, gmail, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I am running a Raspberry Pi with MAIL setup on it.  I'm trying to send mail through the command line.

I have a cronjob that runs the following code on a schedule:
sudo head /home/pi/myNAS/myShare/vol | mail -s "" 2052400919@messaging.sprintpcs.com
The response I get when I run the code on the command line is:
Authorization failed (534 5.7.9 https://support.google.com/mail/bin/ans ... swer=78754 c41sm4496270yhc.53 - gsmtp)

I understand that the issue is related to authorization and security of the account. The code will run without error for a few days after I log-in and use the captcha account authentication, and toggle 'allow less secure apps access' button, but I need something that I can set and forget. Is there another SMTP service that will accomplish the same thing without the issue I'm experiencing with gMail? Somehow I'm being flagged as a security risk every few days. Is there another setting I'm missing. I've feel I've tried everything related to the gmail configuration and setup for linux.

Answer (score 0):

Use an email service provider that supports sending through SMTP. I've had good experiences with [Mandrill](http://mandrill.com/) and [Mailgun](http://www.mailgun.com/). They both have a REST API that you could use CURL with, that might make your life easier.